HTML Canvas context is displaced / shifted on ios
So I'm working on a signature platform, and to handle the signature I wrote this method:
function CursorSign() {
    console.log("Cursor Sign");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("sig_canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



    var isDrawing = false;
    var lastX, lastY;

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    // Mouse events
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrawing);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDrawing);

    // Touch events
    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", startDrawingTouch, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", drawTouch, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchend", stopDrawing, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchend", stopDrawingTouch, false);

    function startDrawing(e) {
        isDrawing = true;
        lastX = e.offsetX;
        lastY = e.offsetY;
    }

    function draw(e) {
        if (!isDrawing) return;
        var x = e.offsetX;
        var y = e.offsetY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
    }

    function stopDrawing() {
        isDrawing = false;
        var imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
        var base64Data = imageData.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, '');
        document.getElementById('<%= signature_hf.ClientID %>').value = base64Data;
    }

    function startDrawingTouch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        var simulatedMouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
            clientX: touch.clientX,
            clientY: touch.clientY
        });
        canvas.dispatchEvent(simulatedMouseEvent);
    }

    function drawTouch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        var simulatedMouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
            clientX: touch.clientX,
            clientY: touch.clientY
        });
        canvas.dispatchEvent(simulatedMouseEvent);
    }

    function stopDrawingTouch() {
        isDrawing = false;
    }
}

On android and pc it works perfectly, the problem is on IOS devices.
On ios, the context of the canvas seems to be rendering above the actual canvas, so if you draw in the middle, the drawing will appear on the top but wont overflow over the rest of the page.
this is my canvas element:
 <div id="canvasContainer"> 
     <canvas id="sig_canvas" name="cnv" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
 </div>

I've tried changing the style of the canvasContainer and sig_canvas as in diferent sizes.
I really have no clue as to what is going on really, also dont have a mac to debug on ios.
